# cannot acces multiply items xml api wunderground

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this code:

Model:

```
class WeatherLookup 
    attr_accessor :temperature, :icon, :condition, :zip, :fcttext

    def fetch_weather(city)
      HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/api_key/forecast/lang:NL/q/IT/#{city.slug}.xml")
     end

    def initialize
      weather_hash = fetch_weather
    end

    def assign_values(weather_hash)
      hourly_forecast_response = weather_hash.parsed_response['response']['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastdays']['forecastday'].first 
      self.fcttext = hourly_forecast_response['fcttext']
      self.icon = hourly_forecast_response['icon_url']

   end


   def initialize(city)  
    @city = city
    weather_hash = fetch_weather(city)
    assign_values(weather_hash)
   end

end
```

city_controller:

```
@weather_lookup = WeatherLookup.new(@city)
```

city_view:

```
 = @weather_lookup.fcttext 
        = image_tag @weather_lookup.icon
```

This work fine...i get the fist dataset of the forecastdays container. The xml from the api looks like this:

```
<response>
<version>0.1</version>
<termsofService>
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html
</termsofService>
<features>
<feature>forecast</feature>
</features>
<forecast>
<txt_forecast>
<date>2:00 AM CEST</date>
<forecastdays>
<forecastday>
<period>0</period>
<icon>clear</icon>
<icon_url>http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif</icon_url>
<title>zondag</title>
<fcttext>
<![CDATA[ Helder. Hoog: 86F. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext>
<fcttext_metric>
<![CDATA[ Helder. Hoog: 30C. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext_metric>
<pop>0</pop>
</forecastday>
<forecastday>
<period>1</period>
<icon>clear</icon>
<icon_url>http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif</icon_url>
<title>zondagnacht</title>
<fcttext>
<![CDATA[ Helder. Laag: 61F. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext>
<fcttext_metric>
<![CDATA[ Helder. Laag: 16C. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext_metric>
<pop>0</pop>
</forecastday>
<forecastday>
<period>2</period>
<icon>partlycloudy</icon>
<icon_url>http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif</icon_url>
<title>maandag</title>
<fcttext>
<![CDATA[ Gedeeltelijk bewolkt. Hoog: 84F. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext>
<fcttext_metric>
<![CDATA[ Gedeeltelijk bewolkt. Hoog: 29C. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext_metric>
<pop>20</pop>
</forecastday>
<forecastday>
<period>3</period>
<icon>clear</icon>
<icon_url>http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif</icon_url>
<title>maandagnacht</title>
<fcttext>
<![CDATA[ Gedeeltelijk bewolkt. Laag: 63F. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext>
<fcttext_metric>
<![CDATA[ Gedeeltelijk bewolkt. Laag: 17C. Light Wind. ]]>
</fcttext_metric>
<pop>0</pop>
</forecastday>
```

I want to acces all the foracasts in the forecasts container by a loop, but when i change the hourly_forecast variable (.first) to .all or none i get the error message "can't convert String into Integer"

Someone ideas to fix this? 
\

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove **.first** from **hourly_forecast**, you are now returning a collection as opposed to a single item. That means your view won't work correctly so you'll need to update your view to render a collection. This is best done with a partial.

city_view will become:

```
= render partial: "weather_lookup", collection: @weather_lookup
```

Then create a partial named **_weather_lookup.html.haml** and include the following:

```
= @weather_lookup.fcttext 
        = image_tag @weather_lookup.icon
```

The underscore in front of the partial's filename is important as this is Rails convention so don't leave it out. When viewed, the partial will be rendered multiple times for every item in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the code as you suggested, but i stil get the error message..'can't convert String into Integer' my log:app/models/weather_lookup.rb:15:in `[]'
app/models/weather_lookup.rb:15:in `assign_values'
app/models/weather_lookup.rb:24:in `initialize'